# angular ng-grid maxWidth not used

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-grid

I am trying to create some autosizing properties for an angular ng-grid element:

```
       for (var i = 0; i < $scope.dates.length; i++) {
            var dateElement = {
                field: 'reportMap.' + $scope.dates[i] + '.hours | round',
                displayName: i + 1,
                minWidth: "27px",
                maxWidth: "46px"

            };

            if ($scope.holidays.indexOf(i + 1) != -1) {
                dateElement.cellTemplate = 'app/partials/gridCell.html';
            }
            $scope.columns.push(dateElement);
```

.....

```
          $scope.gridOptions = {
                data: 'monthlyReports',
                columnDefs: 'columns',
                plugins: [new ngGridFlexibleHeightPlugin()],
                enableRowSelection: false,
                enableColumnResize: true,
                enableSorting: false,
                enableCellSelection: true
            };
```

However, when the field data gets longer than 4 characters the content is hidden. I.e. the width is not increased. I could be using `width: "auto"` but i need to limit the sizing of th columns somewhat...

Why is the column width not increased when the conent gets longer than 27px?

This is what i get setting the width to auto for my date elements:

[image]

This is what i want, dynamic width depending on content! (i also want less padding around the number and the left and right sides of the cell, see the wide cell)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ovveriding the cell properties did the trick in this case, just increasing the constant width one pixel to 28px and overriding the padding made it look good.

```
ngCellText {padding: 2px; text-align: center;}
```